# RandomOverSampling without Replacement

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sampling, oversampling

Is it possible to oversample the dataset without replacement? For [RandomUnderSampling](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.under_sampling.RandomUnderSampler.html), there exist a boolean hyperparameter [replacement]; But, this hyperparameter doesn't exist in [RandomOverSampling](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.RandomOverSampler.html)

Looking at RandomOverSampling Docs:

> Object to over-sample the minority class(es) by picking samples at random with replacement. The bootstrap can be generated in a smoothed manner.

Any suggestions or alternative approaches to follow?

Comment: This is just a warning and does not actually produce any error right?

Comment: Yes, It is a warning. But, "Use at your own risk", and for machineLearning models may fail with producing inconsistent results.

Comment: Ok then just delete sklearn using this `pip uninstall scikit-learn` then install the version you need using `pip install scikit-learn=0.19.1`.